# Homology groups of disjoint sets

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, group-isomorphism, mayer-vietoris-sequence

I have the following question

> If $ X=A\cup B$ where $A$ and $B$ are open non empty sets and $A\cap B = \emptyset$ then $H_n(X) \cong H_n(A) \oplus H_n(B)$.

My attempt is to prove this using Mayer-Vietoris theorem as the following:

$$\cdots \rightarrow H_n(A \cap B)\rightarrow H_n(A) \oplus H_n(B) \rightarrow H_n(X) \rightarrow H_{n-1}(A \cap B) \rightarrow\cdots$$

But $H_n(A \cap  B )  =  0$  for al $n \geq 0$
so we have the following exact sequence

$$\cdots \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow H_n(A) \oplus H_n(B) \rightarrow H_n(X) \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow \cdots$$
so the proof is finished.

Is it right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Alternatively, observe that the image of a simplex $\Delta^n\to X$ would be connected, so would either entirely lie in $A$ or entirely lie in $B$.

Comment: @KentaS this approach can be considered as extracting what is needed from the proof of M-V theorem to prove the conclusion directly.

Comment: @KentaS Also the OP did not specify what homology theory he is refering to. While it is likely he meant singular, it may be something else. The Mayer-Vietoris argument works for all (Eilenberg–Steenrod) theories.